# Sandcastle multiple code examples in one tab control

Tags: xml, xaml, documentation, sandcastle, xml-comments

I'm having trouble using the code examples within sandcastle. I want to be able to have four examples in one tab control however I am unsure how to do this.

```
/// <summary>
/// AnimatedExpander inherits from the .NET Expander to implement additional functionality for animation.
/// </summary>
/// <example> Requirements for use
/// <code source="Examples\Shared.txt" region="UsingCustomControlsXAML" lang="XAML"/>
/// <code source="Examples\Shared.txt" region="UsingCustomControlsCS" lang="CS"/>
/// <para>AnimatedExpander usage example.</para>
/// <code source="Examples\AnimatedExpander.txt" region="AnimatedExpanderDeclarationLeft" lang="XAML" title="Left" />
/// <code source="Examples\AnimatedExpander.txt" region="AnimatedExpanderDeclarationRight" lang="XAML" title="Right" />
/// <code source="Examples\AnimatedExpander.txt" region="AnimatedExpanderDeclarationUp" lang="XAML" title="Up" />
/// <code source="Examples\AnimatedExpander.txt" region="AnimatedExpanderDeclarationDown" lang="XAML" title="Down" />
/// </example>
public class AnimatedExpander : Expander
```

What I get when I build my docs is a tab control with the first two items in but then after I get four separate tab controls, each example in its own.

[image]

My question is how do I get these to display in the same tab control.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for same trouble was proposed in the [Combining several languages in one example (grouping code)](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB/issues/85) issue. It suggests to remove the `title` attributes from `<code>` tag and use different values for `language`.

Also you could use an [Code Snippets File](https://ewsoftware.github.io/MAMLGuide/html/9bef5420-7560-47d9-98ce-0b5d5f46567a.htm) and a [`codeReference`](https://ewsoftware.github.io/MAMLGuide/html/91a45341-e368-463e-a9ed-9e05286d2c25.htm) element to display each `sampleCode` content in own tab. But this is suitable only for conceptual topics.